# Locker Room Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Note: Just to give a heads up, this is not an assignment for my school since I myself don't even know which school wrote this question. Hopefully no misunderstanding occurred.

I found this interesting questions about locker room:

> The locker room of the Rec has N lockers that are labeled 1, 2, . . ., N .
>
> Each locker is locked, but can be opened using its unique key.
>
> Copies of the key to each locker are in its adjacent lockers; i.e. a
> copy of the key to locker i is placed in locker i + 1 and i − 1 (the
> key to locker 1 is only in locker 2 and the key to locker N is only in
> locker N − 1).
>
> T tennis balls are inside T distinct lockers (and you
> know which of the lockers they are in).  You are given keys to M of
> the lockers and your goal is to collect all of the tennis balls by
> opening the least number of lockers.

For pictures you can see it directly to [the file here](https://theresamigler.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/programming_assignment_4.pdf).

I have to give this questions to some freshman but I wanted to make sure first that I myself already have the correct answer beforehand.

What I'm thinking is that:

1. Need to check the ball one by one. So for each ball (ignore the other balls), each key have to visit by traversing to the designated ball. For each key, calculate the steps it takes to visit the ball. The smallest result is stored in an variable called "total steps".
2. Do this exact thing to the next ball and when I get the minimum steps for this current ball. I add this value to "total steps".
3. Special condition applied if there is a ball above the key, then key start traversing from i + 1 and i - 1.

My question is: am I right? I don't want to share the wrong algorithm to others since it's unprofessional. Looking forward to any comments, suggestions and inputs.

Comment: How could this possibly be unclear? He presented a problem and proposed an algorithm. He clearly stated he was not looking for code, just validation.

Comment: @KeithNicholas OP has proposed an algorithm and want to verify that it is correct. Although the tag C should be removed, the question is valid and clear. I don't think it deserves to be closed or downvoted

Comment: How would you validate it without implementing and testing it?

Comment: @MartinJames: Implementing and testing is a useful tool. Doesn't guarantee correctness though, nor having chosen a good algorithm.

Comment: @MartinJames I have 17 years of experience in algorithms and I can validate an algorithm from my knowledge. I can think of a counter example without actually implementing an algorithm and I can do a formal proof if the algorithm is correct. Many algorithm books never write "real" code, they simply use pseudo code as in this question

Comment: I can't see any pseudo code in the question..  Anyway, I'm not convinced either way, so I haven't voted at all on this question yet.

Comment: I've written an answer to an [identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34869244/difficult-dynamic-programming-algorithm/34871911#34871911).

Comment: This question is concurently discussed on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315015)

Comment: @Ami interesting to see the vote count on that duplicate you mention.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Yeah, someone downvoted my answer there too, for some unexplained reason. Oh, well.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service.

Comment: @SwiftArchitect I didn't ask for coding, please read carefully my question.

Comment: This question is being discussed here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315015/why-is-this-question-closed-as-unclear-what-you-are-asking?cb=1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your algorithm will not result in minimum number of steps. You can not consider balls independently. Lets consider the following case: You have only one key for locker number 1 and balls are in lockers 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2. If You consider the balls in the order I have given you will end up with total steps equal to `11 + 9 + 7 + 5 + 3 + 1`, while you can solve the problem in a single pass of 11 steps. You should not ignore the boxes visited on the previous steps.

Comment: Hi, so you mean split into two direction for each key (goLeft and goRight) while keep counting the open locker?

Comment: The opened lockers may become multiple non intersecting intervals using this approach. You can avoid that if you first sort the ball locker numbers

Comment: @MasAdam You also have to take into account a situation where you have balls in door 1 and 6 and keys 4 and 8. The distance from 8 and 4 to 6 is the same, but you have to open door 4 anyway to get to 1, so it should not count towards opening door 6. So, you have to include backtracking in your algorithm as well. You might want to post this riddle on "puzzles and code golf".SE, but keep in mind to make it proper for the site first.

Comment: It's true that it won't solve it in the minimum number of steps, but the question statement asks only for opening the fewest *lockers*. On the reasonable assumption that the algorithm leaves a locker open once it's opened it, and doesn't close and re-open later, OP's algorithm will still solve your example by opening the fewest possible lockers (i.e., all of them).

That's not to say that OP's algorithm works in all cases; but I don't think your proposed counterexample does the job.

Comment: @chiastic-security actually this is a very good point. Maybe consider posting another answer?

Comment: Good point although you can consider the balls in order. You just count from each ball to the closest open locker or other ball. The algorithm is linearithmic

Answer (score 1):

Here is a technique you can use:

Consider each locker (in which there is a ball, of which you have a key and which have none) to be a node in the graph. The nodes will be of two types:

```
A) Lockers having balls
B) Lockers of which you have keys.
C) Lockers which have none
```

Consider all lockers of type-A to be closed and type-B to be open.

From all open lockers, find paths to all closed lockers (from locker type-B) and open the locker in A with min path length. Also, open all lockers of type C which fall in this min-path and move them from category-C to B.

Repeat above step till all lockers in A are opened. Sum of all the min-path lengths that you have come across will be your answer.